# Find folder position number in folder listing

Tags: bash

Suppose i have a `/home` folder with these sub-folders:

```
/home/alex
/home/luigi
/home/marta
```

I can list and count all sub-folders in a folder like this:

```
ls 2>/dev/null -Ubad1 -- /home/* | wc -l
3
```

But I need to find the position (`2`, in this example) if folder (or `basename`) is `===` luigi

Is this possible in bash?

Comment: The order will change depending on how they are sorted.  There really is no "order" other than what is given by the tool you are using to present the data.

Comment: But maybe `ls | awk '/luigi/{print NR}'` is sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After William Pursell comment, this does the job:

```
ls 2>/dev/null -Ubad1 -- /home/* | awk '/luigi$/{print NR}'
2
```

Note the `$` at the end, this will avoid doubles like `joe` and `joey`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a bash shell loop over the wildcard expansion, keeping an index as you go, and report the index when the base directory name matches:

```sh
index=1
for dir in /home/*
do 
  if [[ "$dir" =~ /luigi$ ]]
  then   
    echo $index
    break 
  fi
 ((index++))
done
```

This reports the position (among the expansion of `/home/*`) of the "luigi" directory -- anchored with the directory separator `/` and the end of the line `$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find /home/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk -F/ '$NF=="luigi" {print NR}'
2
$ find /home/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk -F/ '$NF=="alex" {print NR}'
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use find to get subfolders and a list to iterate with indexes:

```
subfolders=($(find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d))
```

Find will get realpath, so if you need relative you can use something like:

```
luigi_folder=${subfolders[2]##*/}
```